# Trigger to increment a table after insert

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I've searched through plenty of previous questions but I'm still not quite understanding.

I have a table, nfl.games and nfl.teams.
 nfl.teams has two columns in particular that keep a running total of

```
rushingyards
passingyards
```

When I insert new games into nfl.games there are 6 columns among others,

```
homerushingyards
homepassingyards
rivalpassingyards
rivalrushingyards
hometeamName
rivalteamName
```

hometeamName and rivalteamName are foreign keys to my teams table. The Trigger I'm trying to create is an AFTER INSERT one that after an insert is made on the nfl.GAMES table, it will take the rushing and passing yards for the home and rival team and update the rushing and passing yards for THAT team in the nfl.TEAMS table.

Honestly I'm quite new to triggers in SQL and the syntax looks confusing so I wanted to just try to update the home teams rushing/passing yards first. If someone could point me in the right direction, what I've though of so far is roughly,

```
CREATE TRIGGER 'yardsUpdate' AFTER INSERT ON 'nfl.games' FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   teams.passingyards = teams.passingyards + games.homepassingyards;
   teams.rushingyards = teams.rushingyards + games.homerushingyards;
   WHERE teams.teamName = games.hometeamName;
END
```

I know this syntax is very off but I think this is a step in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want an `UPDATE` on teams table. In order to refer to the columns of Trigger owner(nfl.games) use the `NEW` pseudorecord

```
CREATE TRIGGER yardsupdate AFTER
     INSERT ON nfl.games
     FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     UPDATE nfl.teams t
     SET t.passingyards = t.passingyards +:new.homepassingyards,
         t.rushingyards = t.rushingyards +:new.homerushingyards
     WHERE t.teamname =:new.hometeamname;
END;
/
```

Comment: Ah okay, this makes much more sense. I will play with this and see if I can come to a solution :) thank you for the help

Comment: And if I wanted to do the same thing but for the rivalTeam would I just append similar SET clause but with new.rivalpassingyards and in the WHERE clause throw an OR t.teamname =:new.rivalteamname?

Comment: @Mikel : The structure of update  and the references to the variable would be same. But,without knowing your actual data it's hard to tell what other conditions you might need. You may ask a separate question if things are not clear to you how to proceed.

Comment: the data is more or less identical, just simply needing to update the homerushing/passing yards with the correct team likewise the rivalrushing/passing yards with the correct team. I believe the structure will be very similar however I think the WHERE clause might need to change is all.